# Text value in text field not refreshing in gtkdialog

Tags: linux, bash, gtk

```
  <hbox>
        <button>
          <input file>bbc_150x150.jpeg</input>
          <variable>bbc</variable>
          <action>txt0=$(eval rsstail -u newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/front_page/rss.xml -u feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/system/latest_published_content/rss.xml -1 -n 1)</action>
      <action>echo $txt0</action>
      <action>refresh:txt0</action>
        </button>  
      </hbox>

      <hbox>
        <button>
          <input file>bbcbusiness_150x150.jpeg</input>
          <action>unset txt0</action>
          <action>txt0=$(eval rsstail -u newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/business/rss.xml -1 -n 1)</action>
        <action>echo $txt0</action>
      <action>refresh:txt0</action>
        </button>  
      </hbox>
<vbox scrollable="true" width="600" height="300">
                <text wrap="false" xalign="0">
                    <variable>txt0</variable>
                    <label>This is a static text.</label>
                    <input file>txt0</input>
                </text>
            </vbox>
```

I am assiging the rsstail's output to a variable named txt0 and then I am trying to print that rsstail's output value present in the news variable onto the text field, but my text field is not refreshing when i click both buttons rsstail output is not changing. its same for both the buttons.

Comment: I still don't know what this bash `gtkdialog` tool is. What is it? It doesn't seem to come with GTK+

Comment: gtkdialog is used to make GUIs out of shell scripts. we should install it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaha echhoing the rsstail output into a text file solved it. like :

```
<hbox>
            <button>
              <input file>bbc_150x150.jpeg</input>
              <variable>bbc</variable>
              <action>echo $(eval rsstail -u newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/front_page/rss.xml -u feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/system/latest_published_content/rss.xml -1 -n 3) > txt0.txt</action>
          <action>echo $txt0.txt</action>
          <action>refresh:txt0</action>
            </button>  
</hbox>

<hbox>
            <button>
              <input file>bbcbusiness_150x150.jpeg</input>
              <action>rm txt0.txt</action>
              <action>echo $(eval rsstail -u newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/business/rss.xml -1 -n 3)>txt0.txt</action>
            <action>echo $txt0.txt</action>
           <action>refresh:txt0</action>
            </button>  
</hbox>

<vbox scrollable="true" width="600" height="300">
                    <text wrap="false" xalign="0">
                        <variable>txt0</variable>
                        <label>This is a static text.</label>
                        <input file>txt0.txt</input>
                    </text>
</vbox>
```